# Update Google calendar from google spreadsheet with script

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-calendar-api

I am trying to update my Google Calendar from a google spreadsheet. 
On each row, I have different events with different dates.
I have found some useful scripts but none that fix the problem of more than one event on each row.
Does anyone has a script for this ?

Comment: Have you Googled a bit ?  Script editor in Sheets allows to invoke Calendar APIs.

Comment: yes, but no script found with multi events on each row. I am an absolute beginner

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.